# Contentful: documentToHtmlString doesn't include embedded image in rich text

Tags: javascript, contentful

I have the following rich text document

```
{  
   "data":{},
   "content":[  
      {  
         "data":{},
         "content":[  
            {  
               "data":{},
               "marks":[ ],
               "value":"test",
               "nodeType":"text"
            }, {  
               "data":{},
               "marks":[],
               "value":"",
               "nodeType":"text"
            }
         ],
         "nodeType":"paragraph"
      },
      {  
         "data":{  
            "target":{  
               "sys":{  
                  "space":{  
                     "sys":{  
                        "type":"Link",
                        "linkType":"Space",
                        "id":"gedg1u5b0yz9"
                     }
                  },
                  "id":"2CzKe2pWvewCiek6w0yyoQ",
                  "type":"Asset",
                  "createdAt":"2019-01-07T22:37:55.473Z",
                  "updatedAt":"2019-01-07T22:37:55.473Z",
                  "environment":{  
                     "sys":{  
                        "id":"master",
                        "type":"Link",
                        "linkType":"Environment"
                     }
                  },
                  "revision":1,
                  "locale":"en-US"
               },
               "fields":{  
                  "title":"Test Image",
                  "description":"Image for testing",
                  "file":{  
                     "url":"//images.ctfassets.net/<hidden>/<hidden>/<hidden>/IMG_2878.JPG",
                     "details":{  
                        "size":3874595,
                        "image":{  
                           "width":5184,
                           "height":3456
                        }
                     },
                     "fileName":"IMG_2878.JPG",
                     "contentType":"image/jpeg"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "content":[],
         "nodeType":"embedded-asset-block"
      },
      {  
         "data":{},
         "content":[  
            {  
               "data":{},
               "marks":[],
               "value":"",
               "nodeType":"text"
            }
         ],
         "nodeType":"paragraph"
      }
   ],
   "nodeType":"document"
}
```

When I use documentToHtmlString (from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer)

```
documentToHtmlString(document);
```

It outputs the following

```
<p>test</p><p></p>
```

Anyone know how to get it to output the img tag as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/issues/58#issuecomment-452236848

You need to specify how to render that
You can find more about it here https://github.com/contentful/rich-text/tree/master/packages/rich-text-html-renderer#usage

```
import { BLOCKS } from '@contentful/rich-text-types';
import { documentToHtmlString } from '@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer';

const options = {
  renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node) => `<custom-component>${customComponentRenderer(node)}</custom-component>`
  }
}

documentToHtmlString(document, options);
```

My specific resolution was:

```
const options = {
    renderNode: {
        [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: ({ data: { target: { fields }}}) =>
            `<img src="${fields.file.url}" height="${fields.file.details.image.height}" width="${fields.file.details.image.width}" alt="${fields.description}"/>`,
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const options = {
    renderNode: {
        [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: ({ data: { target: { fields }}}) =>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `<img src="${fields.file['en-GB'].url}" alt="${fields.title['en-GB']}"/>`}} />,
    },
};
```

I found i needed to set `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for it to render properly in the browser.

Comment: I think thats because you are wrapping the image with a div,  and I'm still not necessarily sure that you need it.

Comment: it was rendering the url path as a string and not html, not sure there is another way to render without the div, for reference - https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 1):

This is the original answer and hardcoded dynamic values,
I hope it can help the reader to have an immediate answer to the specific problem:

```
let options = {
  renderNode: {
    'embedded-asset-block': (node) =>
      `<img class="img-fluid" src="${node.data.target.fields.file.url}"/>`
  }
}
let bodyHTML = body ? documentToHtmlString(body, options) : ''
```

Comment: Why is this "the best way"? You took the original answer and hardcoded dynamic values.

Comment: @SethMcClaine  Your answer is excellent for a good study.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on the `fields` property existing.

I'm using Contentful with SvelteKit via GraphQL. I don't know whether it's my setup or whether the Contentful API has changed, but the node data received by my `renderNode` options callback (as seen in the other answers) doesn't contain `fields`.

Contentful's recommended `<custom-component>` approach doesn't work for me in SvelteKit.

I use the `renderNode` callback to save the asset link info and return a unique text "marker" that is embedded into the result string. After `documentToHtmlString()` completes, I fetch the image associated with each link and then search-and-replace the marker with the final HTML.

Define this function `richTextToHTML()` and call `html = await richTextToHTML(json)` instead of `html = documentToHtmlString(json)`. You may need to replace `contentfulFetch()` with your query call and adjust the resulting `<img>` width and height.

```
async function richTextToHTML( json )
{
    const asset_links = [];
    const options = {
        renderNode: {
            [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]:
                (node) => { return `[embedded-asset-block:${asset_links.push(node.data.target.sys)}]`; }
        }
    };

    let html = documentToHtmlString( json, options );

    for (let i=0; i<asset_links.length; ++i) {
        const link = asset_links[i]
        const asset_query = `
        {
            asset(id:"${link.id}")
            {
                title
                description
                url
                width
                height
            }
        }
        `

        let replacement = '';
        const response = await contentfulFetch(asset_query);
        if (response.ok) {
            const asset = (await response.json()).data.asset;
            replacement = `<img src="${asset.url}" alt="${asset.description}" style="max-width:800px; height:auto;">`;
            const marker = `[embedded-asset-block:${i+1}]`;
            html = html.replace( marker, replacement );
        }
    }

    return html;
}
```